# VHDL-controling LCD screen ALTERA DE 2

Tags: vhdl

heloo I am currently working on ALTERA DE2 board . I want to use the LCD screen . I manged to turn it on . In this code the lcd_bus is the output of the lcd  for exmaple if the code for number one is : "0100110001"
 so if I write in the code :
WHEN 1 => lcd_bus <= "0100110001" then I will see output lcd_bus = 0100110001 . here is the code for this exmaple :

```
LIBRARY ieee;
 USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
 USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
 USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

 ENTITY lcd_user_logic IS


                        GENERIC (display_resolution : INTEGER :=23;   -- counter to get to the lowest ferquncy 
                                    display_counter: INTEGER :=8);      -- counter to get to 97KHz ferquincy 

 PORT(



        lcd_bus_ones : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 DOWNTO 0);




 --COUNTER_VECTOR :IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(display_counter downto 0);
 lcd_busy : IN STD_LOGIC; --lcd controller busy/idle feedback
 clk : IN STD_LOGIC; --system clock
 lcd_clk : OUT STD_LOGIC;
 reset_n : OUT STD_LOGIC;
 lcd_enable : buffer STD_LOGIC; --lcd enable received from lcd controller
 lcd_bus : BUFFER STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 DOWNTO 0)); --data andcontrol signals
 --The MSB is the rs signal, followed by the rw signal.
 -- The other 8 bits are the data bits.
 END lcd_user_logic;

 ARCHITECTURE behavior OF lcd_user_logic IS


signal lcd_bus_ones_signal :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(display_counter+1 downto 0);



 BEGIN

 lcd_bus_ones_signal<=lcd_bus_ones;





 PROCESS(clk,lcd_bus_ones,lcd_bus_ones_signal)
 VARIABLE char : INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 12 := 0;
        BEGIN

                IF(clk'EVENT AND clk = '1') THEN

                    IF(lcd_busy = '0' AND lcd_enable = '0') THEN
                    --  lcd_bus <=  lcd_bus_ones;   
                            lcd_enable <= '1';
                                IF(char < 12) THEN
                                        char := char + 1;
                END IF;
 CASE char IS



                    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------this is the test 

                  WHEN 1 => lcd_bus <="1000110001";





 WHEN OTHERS => lcd_enable <= '0';
 END CASE;
 ELSE
 lcd_enable <= '0';
 END IF;
 END IF;
 END PROCESS;





 reset_n <= '1';
 lcd_clk <= clk;



 END behavior;
```

and the output will be indeed  lcd_bus <="1000110001"

[image]

how ever if for exmaple I want to enter a value to lcd_bus like this , lcd_bus <=lcd_bus_ones then I get lcd_bus = "0000000000" 
and the code looks like this :

```
LIBRARY ieee;
 USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
 USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
 USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

 ENTITY lcd_user_logic IS


                        GENERIC (display_resolution : INTEGER :=23;   -- counter to get to the lowest ferquncy 
                                    display_counter: INTEGER :=8);      -- counter to get to 97KHz ferquincy 

 PORT(



        lcd_bus_ones : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 DOWNTO 0);




 --COUNTER_VECTOR :IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(display_counter downto 0);
 lcd_busy : IN STD_LOGIC; --lcd controller busy/idle feedback
 clk : IN STD_LOGIC; --system clock
 lcd_clk : OUT STD_LOGIC;
 reset_n : OUT STD_LOGIC;
 lcd_enable : buffer STD_LOGIC; --lcd enable received from lcd controller
 lcd_bus : BUFFER STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 DOWNTO 0)); --data andcontrol signals
 --The MSB is the rs signal, followed by the rw signal.
 -- The other 8 bits are the data bits.
 END lcd_user_logic;

 ARCHITECTURE behavior OF lcd_user_logic IS


signal lcd_bus_ones_signal :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(display_counter+1 downto 0);



 BEGIN

 lcd_bus_ones_signal<=lcd_bus_ones;












 PROCESS(clk,lcd_bus_ones,lcd_bus_ones_signal)
 VARIABLE char : INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 12 := 0;
        BEGIN

                IF(clk'EVENT AND clk = '1') THEN

                    IF(lcd_busy = '0' AND lcd_enable = '0') THEN
                    --  lcd_bus <=  lcd_bus_ones;   
                            lcd_enable <= '1';
                                IF(char < 12) THEN
                                        char := char + 1;
                END IF;
 CASE char IS



                    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------this is the test 

                  WHEN 1 => lcd_bus <=lcd_bus_ones;






 WHEN OTHERS => lcd_enable <= '0';
 END CASE;
 ELSE
 lcd_enable <= '0';
 END IF;
 END IF;
 END PROCESS;







 reset_n <= '1';
 lcd_clk <= clk;



 END behavior;
```

so the out put will look like this

[image]

the problem is with this statment :
IF(lcd_busy = '0' AND lcd_enable = '0') THEN

any one have idea how to fix this problem |?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not enough reputation to comment yet.

It's really hard to see what's going on for sure with only 2 or 3 signals that you have shown in your waveform display. Please add at least `lcd_busy` and `lcd_enable` to your waveforms. It seems like your `lcd_busy` signal may be set to something other than '0'. I have simulated the code, and the assignment to the `lcd_bus_ones` signal worked fine for me.

Also, it would be nice to see what's going on outside this entity, if possible.

Do you want `char` to stop at 12? The way it's defined now, it will reach 12, and the assignment in question will never occur again, unless you provide a way to reset `char`.